# Read xml data saved in text file using R

Tags: r, xml

I have a data saved in .txt file containing XML. It has around 35k lines with the first line as header, and I want to extract this data to a dataframe.

I used readLines to read the data into R. An excerpt from the data looks like below:

```
[1] "H|TASK_ID|TASK_REFERENCE|TASK_NAME|TASK_TYPE|TASK_RAISED_TS|TASK_STATE|TASK_VIEWED_FLAG|TASK_OUTCOME|CURRENT_QUEUE|QUEUE_CHANGE_TS|TASK_XML_DATA|SCORE_XML_DATA|CREATED_TS|CREATED_BY|LAST_UPDATED_TS|LAST_UPDATED_BY|VERSION_NO|TASK_ADOPTED_FLAG"

[2] "B|\"12\"|\"137####_2A62###\"|\"137####_2A62###\"|\"Claim\"|\"14APR2015:23:36:04\"|\"AwaitingTriageEast\"|\"N\"|\" \"|\"4\"|\".\"|\"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><tasks xmlns=\"xyz.com/network/workbench/task\"><task><taskxml><Claim prDocumentIdentifier=\"137####_2A62###\"><ID>519_1</ID><ClaimNumber>137####_2A62###</ClaimNumber><SearchClaimNumber>2A62###</SearchClaimNumber><PolicyNumber>28352##_SP23A2####</PolicyNumber><SearchPolicyNumber>SP23A2####</SearchPolicyNumber><AmendmentNumber>5007####</AmendmentNumber><AmendmentDatetime>2016-10-31T14:44:02</AmendmentDatetime><FreeTextDescription>INS PASSENGER IN UNINSURED AUTOMOBILE THAT VEERED OFF THE RD INTO A DITCH</FreeTextDescription><ClaimCauses><ClaimCause><ActualValue>THIRD PARTY STRUCK INSURED'S PARKED VEHICLE</ActualValue><Category>MOTOR_ACCIDENT_TP_HIT_FP</Category></ClaimCause></ClaimCauses><IncidentDate>2006-10-13</IncidentDate><IncidentTime>14:30:00.000</IncidentTime><IncidentDateTime>2006-10-13T14:30:... <truncated>
```

How do I proceed from here to make a data frame? I am new to XML related packages. So any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: the data seems to be | pipe separated rather than xml. Is it so?

Comment: there's XML in at least one of the fields.

Comment: @amrrs - The data is pipe separated with some columns containing xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your data is in file "df.txt". Then simply read table with sep = "|" like:

```
df = read.table("df.txt", sep="|")
```

Comment: @ Aleksandr - Thanks for the pointer. I'm now getting an error `Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 368 did not have 19 elements`. How to skip these specific rows while reading the data?

Comment: Try adding header = TRUE, fill = TRUE i.e. read.table("df.txt", sep="|", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)

Comment: @ Aleksandr - This works like a charm. However, 2 of the columns in the dataframe is still in XML format. One of them looks as follows: `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><tasks xmlns=\"xyz.com/network/workbench/task\"><task><taskxml><Claim prDocumentIdentifier=\"137####_2A6 2###\"><ID>519_1</ID><ClaimNumber>137####_2A62###</ClaimNumber><SearchClaimNumber>2A62###</SearchClaimNumber><PolicyNumber>28352##_SP23A2####</PolicyNumber><SearchPolicyNumber>SP23A2####</SearchPolicyNumber>`. Any pointers on how to extract useful information from these columns?

Comment: You should know, what data you want to take from column 2, otherwise your question is unclear.

Comment: I have exported the column (having XML content) in the dataframe as a seperate XML file. When I'm trying to read that into R using `xmlParse("xyz.xml")`, I'm getting the following error: `Error: 1: String not started expecting ' or "
2: Malformed declaration expecting version
3: Blank needed here
4: parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected
5: AttValue: " or ' expected
6: attributes construct error
7: Couldn't find end of Start Tag tasks line 1
8: Extra content at the end of the document`. How do you extract the information from the different tags like <task> etc..?

Comment: I think you should open another question as it is unclear what data you are using. Provide a data sample.